# Term for this type of negation: "Not for X I don't"

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis, negation

> - You got any more pot?
> - **Not** for $9 an hour **I don't.**

What is this type of negation called? These are the lines from a movie script. I've come across this sentence structure quite a few times but I know next to nothing about it. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: In AE, we understand it this way: "I don't have any more, at least not for $9 an hour!" The two negatives do not fight each other.

Comment: In the UK, "Not for £8 an hour I haven't" shows the repeat negation. It underlines, rather than flips, the first negator.